# Android: Implementing AES_256/GCM/NoPadding with 16byte iv on api 21+

Tags: android, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to implement AES_256/GCM/NoPadding with 16byte iv on api 21+. I have kotlin code which works on desktop but throws exception `InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Expected IV length of 12 but was 16`. I checked it on emulator with API level 29. Android document do not mention about IV length for AES/GCM. But most of the code samples use 12 byte IV.

According to [Android's cryptography guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography) AES_256/GCM/NoPadding is supported on API level 26+. Our min API level is 21. We can not change backend code which generates/consumes encrypted data.

Is it mandatory in Android to use 12byte IV for AES-256/GCM? Is there any external library which can work on API 21+ with 16 byte IV and AES-256/GCM?

```
private val algo = "AES_256/GCM/NoPadding"

private var hex = Hex()

fun encrypt(accessToken: String, text: String): String {
    val (iv, pbkdfKeyHex) = extractKeyFromToken(accessToken)

    val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(pbkdfKeyHex, "AES")
    val encryptor = Cipher.getInstance(algo)
    encryptor.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, GCMParameterSpec(128, iv))
    val encrypted = encryptor.doFinal(text.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    val ivText = hex.toString(iv)
    val encryptedTxt = hex.toString(encrypted)

    val (encryptedText, authTag) = encryptedTxt.chunked(encryptedTxt.length - 32)

    return "${ivText}.${authTag}.${encryptedText}"
}

fun decrypt(accessToken: String, text: String): String {
    val (_, pbkdfKeyHex) = extractKeyFromToken(accessToken)
    val (ivText, authTag, encryptedText) = text.split(".")

    val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(pbkdfKeyHex, "AES")
    val decryptor = Cipher.getInstance(algo)
    val iv = hex.toBytes(ivText)
    decryptor.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, GCMParameterSpec(128, iv))
    val encryptedTxt = encryptedText + authTag
    val decrypted = decryptor.doFinal(hex.toBytes(encryptedTxt))
    return decrypted.decodeToString()
}
```

Comment: No, you can also use a 16 bytes IV/nonce. However, the recommended length is 12 bytes, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41610) for more details, and you may lose compatibility with libraries that follow the recommendation. For 21+ you could try BouncyCastle (should work, also for 16 bytes, but not tested).

Comment: The NIST standard for GCM specifies that implementations should work with a 96 bit nonce, and that the support for other sizes is optional. So it is not that strange if you walk into this kind of issue.  Yes, other implementations such as Bouncy Castle should avoid this trap, with the disadvantage that their engines are software only.

Comment: As mentioned in these urls it should support 96+ bits for iv, but Android is just throwing exception. Even worse, Android documentation does not mention anything about iv restrictions.